# Hide keyboard after search in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I'd like the virtual keyboard to disappear after the search is clicked. This is the code I have so far:

```
query.EditorAction += (sender, e) => {

            if (e.ActionId == ImeAction.Search) 
            {
                HideKeyboard ();
                pushSearch();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
        };

private void HideKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(query.WindowToken, 0);
    }
```

In XML:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/query"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Zoek totem" />
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpIeA.jpg) is while typing (before pressing the magnifying glass) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/layCI.jpg) is after.

If I debug and put a breakpoint on pushSearch() inside the if, it never gets called.

Anyone know what I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void HideKeyboard ()
    { 
        View View = CurrentFocus;
        if (View != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService (Context.InputMethodService);
            inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow (View.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, same thing. It goes out of focus, but the keyboard stays. [This](http://i.imgur.com/8jS27MO.jpg) is while typing (before pressing the magnifying glass) and [this](http://i.imgur.com/g4RnLjt.jpg) is after.

Comment: Where are you calling the method from? Activity or Fragment?

Comment: No, it stays the same.

Comment: Instead of `inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow (View.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);` try `inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow (Control.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);`

Comment: What namespace is Control.WindowToken?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,take the token of window from currentfocus:

```
  InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)this.GetSystemService (Context.InputMethodService);
            inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow (this.CurrentFocus.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.NotAlways);
```